# jboss kie workbench:how can i replace maven central repository url to my company local repo url in kie workbench

Tags: java, maven, jboss, workbench, kie

my local server can not access the maven central repository(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) ,so i meet the below issue when i upload a artifact to KIE workbench ,and how can i replace the maven central repository url to my company lo

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [M2Servlet] in context with path [/kie-drools-wb] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.8
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.mybatis:mybatis-parent:pom:21 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.mybatis:mybatis-parent:pom:21 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out @ line 20, column 11
for project org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.8
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.getDistributionManagement(GuvnorM2Repository.java:462)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.deployArtifact(GuvnorM2Repository.java:373)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.deployArtifact(GuvnorM2Repository.java:178)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deployArtifact(GuvnorM2Repository$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2RepoServiceImpl.deployJar(M2RepoServiceImpl.java:55)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2RepoServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deployJar(M2RepoServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.helpers.HttpPostHelper.uploadJar(HttpPostHelper.java:168)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.helpers.HttpPostHelper.upload(HttpPostHelper.java:122)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.helpers.HttpPostHelper.handle(HttpPostHelper.java:62)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2Servlet.doPost(M2Servlet.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:69)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.kie.integration.tomcat.JACCValve.invoke(JACCValve.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
```

Comment: i search the setting.xml in jboss kie workbench working dir ,but i get nothing,so i do not know kie workbench inside maven server how to work with maven central repository(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Answer (score 1):

solved it myself :update pom-4.0.0.xml file setting of maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar in kie-drools-wb's lib ,replace the repository's setting by myselft ,and save and replace server kie-drools-wb's lib jar with modification ,and clean up the cache ,restart server

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```